# Laravel, Vue.js commenting system pagination

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, vue.js, axios

I am building blog commenting system, using laravel 5.8 and vue.js. 
I want to add paginate function to comments.

Now I can display five comments, and after I click load more,

> I want to show next five comments.

I have no idea how to accomplish. I am glad if someone helps me out.

comments.vue

```
<template >
<div class="commentarea">
        <div class="comment-posts" >
            <div class="user-comment-area" >
                <div class="user-post">
                    <img src="" alt="" >user
                    <input type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="comments-buttons">
                    <button class="cancel-button">Cancel</button>
                    <button class="comment-button">Comment</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="reply-comment" v-if="comment.user" v-for="comment in comments" :key="comment.id" :post="comment">
                 <div class="user-comment" >
                    <div class="user">
                        <!--<img src="" alt="" >-->
                        <avatar :username="comment.user.name" :size="50" ></avatar>
                    </div>
                    <div class="user-name">
                        <span class="comment-name">{{ comment.user.name }}</span>
                        <p> {{ comment.body }} </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="reply">
                    <div class="seemorecomments">
                        <a href="">see more</a>
                    </div>
                    <button class="reply-button">
                        <i class="fas fa-reply"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button @click="fetchComments" class="load">Load More</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
<script>
import Avatar from 'vue-avatar'
export default {
    props: ['post'],
    components: {
        Avatar
    },
    mounted() {
        this.fetchComments()
    },
    data: () => ({
        comments: {
            data: []
        }
    }),
       methods: {
    fetchComments() {
        axios.get(`/results/${this.post.id}/comments`).then((response) => {
            this.comments = response.data.data
        })
    }
}
}
</script>
```

commentsController.php

```
public function index(Post $post)
{
    return $post->comments()->with('user')->paginate(5);
}
```

ResultsController.php

```
public function show(Post $post)
{
    $recommended_posts = Post::latest()
                        ->whereDate('date','>',date('Y-m-d'))
                        ->where('category_id','=',$post->category_id)
                        ->where('id','!=',$post->id)
                        ->limit(7)
                        ->get();

    // load the post comments here
    $post->load('comments');
    $posts['particular_post'] = $post;
    $posts['recommended_posts'] = $recommended_posts;

    return view('posts.show',compact('posts'));
}
```

show.blade.php

```
<comments-component :post="{{ $posts['particular_post'] }}"></comments-component>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('results/{post}', 'ResultsController@show')->name('posts.show');
Route::get('results/{post}/comments', 'CommentsController@index');
```

Comment: Have you looked into using [Bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/pagination/)? Really helped with the pagination stuff for me on a Vue.js / Laravel project.

Comment: Sorry but I don't use bootstrap model...

Comment: Why not? You want to paginate a collection. You have options. Either use Laravel's default [pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/pagination#displaying-pagination-results) or the aforementioned Bootstrap-vue library. No need to re-invent the wheel here

Comment: I have to organize front end either, so I cannot use template...